# open api 3 default Array generation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, openapi-generator

My API definition is as follows:

```
/api:
  get:
  ...
  parameters:
     - name: "tags"
       in: "query"
       description: "some description"
       required: false
       schema:
         type: "array"
         items:
           type: "string"
  ....
```

We are using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin:3.3.5` for code generation.

The API param that is generated: `@ApiParam(value = "description", defaultValue = "new ArrayList<>()")`

The actual param that the Controller receives is not empty and contains the literal `new ArrayList<>()` as the first element:

```
String first = tags.get(0);
assert "new ArrayList<>()".equals(first) //true
```

I couldn't find any param value that controls this behaviour (like defaultValue). 
How can I make the param to be null or at least, an empty list?

*using sagger in a Spring boot app:*

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>${io.springfox.swagger.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

*openapitools generator config options*

```
  <configOptions>
      <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
      <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
      <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
      <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
      <useTags>true</useTags>
  </configOptions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer generator version already fixes this issue:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
    ...
</plugin>
```

Also, add Jackson databind-nullable

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
  <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem here, but could not get it to work.
But you can maybe add some validation to see if list contains at least one element, e.g.

```
/api:
  get:
  ...
  parameters:
   - name: "tags"
     in: "query"
     description: "some description"
     required: false
     schema:
       type: "array"
       minItems: 1
       items:
         type: "string"
  ....
```